# java try-catch-finally recursion question

Tags: java, recursion, try-catch, finally

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo();
    }

    public static void foo() {
        try {
            System.out.println("try");
            foo();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("catch");
            foo();
        } finally {
                System.out.println("finally");
                foo();
        }
    }
}
```

who can explain the output of this code ?

1.output on eclipse   (endless) client mode:

```
    try
    try
    ....


    ...
    ...
    tryfinallyfinally
    tryfinallyfinally
    try
    try
    try
    tryfinallyfinally
    tryfinallyfinally
    try
    tryfinallyfinally
    tryfinallyfinally
    try
    ....
    ....
```

2.output on linux (crash) server mode:

```
    try
    try
    ...

    ...
    try
    try
    try
    try
    try
    try
    MISSING EXCEPTION HANDLER for pc 0x00002aaaab1c53f0 and handler bci -1
       Exception:

     Compiled exception table :
    ExceptionHandlerTable (size = 3304 bytes)
    catch_pco = 700 (1 entries)
      bci -1 at scope depth 0 -> pco 11039
    catch_pco = 1736 (1 entries)
      bci -1 at scope depth 0 -> pco 11473
    catch_pco = 1756 (1 entries)
      bci -1 at scope depth 0 -> pco 11433
    catch_pco = 1776 (1 entries)
```

Comment: ***who can explain the output of this code ?***: May be **You**. What did you get when you run this?

Comment: ... stackoverflow

Comment: Output is indeed unexpected:

try
try
try
tryfinallyfinally
tryfinallyfinally
try
tryfinallyfinally
tryfinallyfinally
try
try
tryfinallyfinally
tryfinallyfinally
try
tryfinallyfinally
tryfinallyfinally
try
try
try
try

Comment: What were you expecting to happen? I wouldn't expect anything sensible. You're catching a StackOverflowError and then immediately proceeding to call another method (one which will call quite a few methods itself).

Comment: Can you explain what you hope to achieve by doing this? i.e. does it have a point?

Comment: some new lines are not printed, because stack overflows somewhere after `write(s)` and before `newLine()` is called in PrintStream.

Answer (score 8):

I think I remember this from the book "Java Puzzlers". The try block does an unbounded recursion which quickly results in a StackOverflowError being thrown. The try and catch blocks *resume* the recursion, but with a correspondingly smaller remaining stack. However, the the remaining stack gets larger again as each recursive call returns...

The end result is a call graph that forms a tree with the depth depending on the size of the stack; with the default stack size of mainstream JVMs the tree gets so large that you'd have to wait for many, *many* billions of years for it to be completely traversed and the program to terminate.

**Edit:** That's what you're seeing in client mode: the traversal of the call graph. What you're seeing on Linux in server mode is either a JVM bug or a hardware flaw (faulty RAM can have this effect).

Comment: My guess is it was a bug in the JIT on Linux.