# Recursive call in the try-catch statement

Tags: java, recursion

I have the following snippet of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    foo();
}
public static void foo() {
    try {
        foo();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        foo();
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain me what's going on here? In details, please.

---

I have changed this piece and added `println` methods to show something:

```
...
try {
    System.out.println("+");
    foo();
} catch (Throwable t) {
    System.out.println("-");
    foo();
}
...
```

I'm getting something like this (the process hasn't stopped):

```
+
+
+
+
+--
+--
+
+--
+--
+
+
+--
+--
+
+--
+--
+
+
+
+--
+--
```

Comment: Looks similar to this question: [java try-catch-finally recursion question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744723/java-try-catch-finally-recursion-question)

Comment: The link @Trobbins provided should explain the behavior. You arent getting the exception because your catch is for trowable(meaning it will catch pretty much anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way `foo` can exit is because of stackoverflow. We can simulate the effect by

```
public static void foo(int i)
{
    if(i>=N) return; // stack too deep

    foo(i+1);
    foo(i+1);
}
```

which is exponentially expensive w.r.t to the max stack depth.

On my machine, the time it takes is about `6ns * 2^N`

The max stack depth is over 10,000, so it will take about

```
        10000000000000000000000000000000
        .... 
        (thousands of zeros)  
        ... 
        00000000000000000000000000000000
```

years to finish the program, give or take a constant factor:)

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the same method indefinitely. This means the a StackOverflowError will be thrown.

But because you are catching it ([StackOverflowError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) is not an exception, it is java.lang.Error, which is a java.lang.Throwable) the application will not stop, it will continue recursing, it will not stop at all.

When I tried to decrease the stack size to the minimum (`-Xss160k -Xoss1k`) it didn't help.

I know I didn't provide an explanation why this happens, I need to profile the code in order to get more information, but this is an interesting issue, maybe someone with deep expertise in JVM internals knows exactly what happened.